# How to make a UIImageView a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a UIImageView like so:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.1;

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Couple of issues/questions:

1. How do I make this a clickable button?
2. I want to link to Settings (in my app) but do I have to create that image wheel like the settings icon that so many apps use or is it standard icon in iOS 7?
   This is the icon I'm talking about: [image: iOS Settings Icon]
3. Why doesn't my border show up?

Comment: you can put a UIButton of custom type over your imageview

Comment: why don't you try to add a UIButton and then add an background image on that button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here 2 choice u have to use your method

.h file

```
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>  //for radius and corner



1. UIButton


   UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [btn1 setTitle:@"Cool title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(7, 7, 150, 160)];
[btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(selectFav) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn1];


-(void) selectFav

{  //what ever you do like


 }

2. UITap Gesture for UIImage View


 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

  imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
  imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
  imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
 imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.1;


   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapGesture:)];

 tapGesture1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[tapGesture1 setDelegate:self];

 [imgView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture1];

[self.view addSubview:imageView];

- (void) tapGesture: (id)sender
{
 //handle Tap...
}
```

Comment: in my choice mostly use in the unbutton for your images , its fine to work

Answer (score 2):

1) If you want a button, you should use a [UIButton](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html&ei=coOiU9eSIM-_uASvyoHoDg&usg=AFQjCNHLtmHeD5lmPT20QMIkzQ3FgyM3dQ&sig2=ps-mJDMIsD-zEzix3VXw-g&bvm=bv.69411363,d.c2E) and use `[UIButton setImage: forState:]`

2) Alternatively, you can add a [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEAQFjAE&url=https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=kYOiU8OnBJKxuASq8YHQDQ&usg=AFQjCNGFUa7Xz6MoFNWz9sjRWtrzSX5wYQ&sig2=fIz0z8_8SvIBQpgxe3fX9A&bvm=bv.69411363,d.c2E) to your current `UIImageView`

Comment: Yeah i will switch to a UIButton

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.1;

/* Here's the button Start */
UIButton *theButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, imageView.frame.origin.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];
theButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
theButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
[theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[imageView addSubview:theButton];
/* Here's the button End */

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Your border:

```
0.1 means is 1/10th of a point - try 1.0 for a nice fine line
```

Also set:

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

1:if you have image view and want to clickable

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

2: Add gesture to image view like this, but don’t forget to setUserInteractionEnabled:YES

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *TapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(markerMove:)];

    [TapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [TapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer: TapGestureRecognizer];
```